# Can't get SmarterMail to work on fresh Windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, smtp, email-server, email

Really having trouble with this, I've been through all the guides I can find and get stuck, using latest version of Smartermail 8 on Windows 2008 with IIS7.5.

I have it setup so I can SEND emails fine, and login etc, but it just wont RECEIVE emails.  I always get this back:

> Technical details of permanent
>   failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the
>   recipient domain. We recommend
>   contacting the other email provider
>   for further information about the
>   cause of this error. The error that
>   the other server returned was: 550 550
>   5.7.1 Unable to relay for xxx@scirra.com (state 14).

I followed this guide:

http://portal.smartertools.com/KB/a31/cant-receive-mail.aspx

And got these results, which make little sense to me.  I've also included some images of my setup, if someone can spot the obvious fault?

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I do:
netstat -abnp tcp

I get only one listening on port 25:

TCP 127.0.0.1:25 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING

My smartermail web server config is set to all IP addresses on port 9998, I've tried 25 as well but not luck. SMTP service is stopped in services as well.

Any help greatly appreciated, I don't understand much of this.

### Update

Is this now correct?
[image]

### Update 2

MX records look like they are set up correctly.  Still it's bouncing with same message.

Some people say I need to disable SMTP Service, others say leave it running.  When I:

`telnet 84.45.57.142 25` I get the response `220 tom.scirra.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service`  This is with the SMTP service running.

When SMTP service is NOT running I get the response:

`Could not open connection to the host, on port 25`

When I `netstat -abnp tcp` I get `TCP 127.0.0.1:25   0.0.0.0:0   LISTENING [MailService.exe]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what it looks like you need based upon a little digging around...

1. You may need to update your A Record for mail.scirra.com. It looks like it is currently identifying 84.45.57.143, while it seems that your mail server is on 84.45.57.142 (based upon your example/description and port scanning/direct connecting).
2. You might also consider consider setting up a MX Record for your scirra.com domain, as there does not currently appear to be one.

Those two steps should get inbound mail flowing for your scirra.com domain if SmarterMail 8 is indeed running on 84.45.57.142.

Comment: Thanks!  Step 2 though (please treat me like a moron), what do I put in FDQN and child domain?  I'm really confused about all of this

Comment: It's actually pretty straight forward. It's basically similar to adding an A Record entry, where you call out a MX Record type instead, assigned a weight (can be anything, if there is only one MX record defined for the domain) and identify mail.scirra.com (if that is your desired incoming mail host). The mail.scirra.com just needs to be established via an A Record beforehand. It will look something like "mx 10 mail.scirra.com" (without the quotes).

Comment: Thanks user, I updated answer, is that correct?

Comment: It looks good, but you might consider your updating SMTP "announce" or actual host name to mail.scirra.com vs. tom.scirra.com, if you are also planning to utilize the same setup for outbound SMTP as well.

Comment: Still getting same email bounce back, how do I change my SMTP announce to mail.scirra.com?  I can't see tom.scirra.com anywhere.  Also, the telnet command now works fine!  I think I'm getting somewhere.  Under 'configure smartermail server config' it has a box which says `website settings: IP-> All IP addesses | Port->9998` does port need to be 25 or is that something different?

Comment: You may have to disable the SMTP service that "tags" along with IIS. The SMTP response banner seems to indicate the Microsoft SMTP answering. I wasn't sure if SmartMail piggy-backed off of Microsoft's SMTP. If it is a case where there are two separate SMTP for each, then after you disable the Microsoft one, you should be able to reassign the SmarterMail SMTP to port 25. The SMTP announce may be configurable within SmarterMail.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it so much.  I managed to change it from tom.scirra.com to mail.scirra.com.  Still the same behaviour though :(

Comment: You may have a mis-match on the port vs. application assignments for SmarterMail. It looks like its webmail is now answering on port 25!

Answer (score 0):

I SEE WHAT YOU DID!
Change that MX record from "mail" to just an empty string.

As you can see here, when I ask who handles mail for scirra.com, I get no record, but when I ask who handles mail for "mail.scirra.com" I get the right answer.

You want that MX record to just be for "scirra.com," so go and edit that record so the field labeled "Host or Child Domain" in the windows DNS manager is blank!

[image]

BTW, hitting mail.scirra.com on port 25 is working for me...

Comment: I'm full of stupid, I really don't get this lol, thanks for your answer but I deleted my MX record and add it again, what am I putting in each box?  Host or child domain should be `mail` right?  And FQDN should be `scirra.com`?

Comment: Not so fast... There's a few other DNS issues lurking around here. If you ping mail.scirra.com, the response is 84.45.57.143 - which is NOT 84.45.57.142 in Tom's example/description! A port scan show port 25 answering up on 84.45.57.142 - NOT 84.45.57.143. A little bit of a mix-up...

Comment: First, make sure that mail.scirra.com is pointing to 84.45.57.142. Then, when you go to put in the MX record, you want it to look like this: http://i.imgur.com/26vFg.png (the part that says scirra.com. should be pre-filled)

Comment: I update my answer, thanks for your help so far!  I might need to leave it overnight to propogate though

Comment: It looks like what you did is correct! My MX check indicates that everything should be OK. Like you said, it might take some time to propagate across the internet... Oh, if my answer helped, can you do me a favor and hit that checkmark next to my post? Thanks a lot!